# extrapolate turning points for a sine weighted moving average?

Tags: signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, moving-average

On a stationary signal a sine-weighted moving average is calculated (SWMA: the coefficient vector looks like the first (>0) part of a sinusoid). The SWMA looks like this: very smooth:

[image]

The future is unknown, but what would be the best way to anticipate the next turning point if you are at the first blue arrow? How would you anticipate the next turning point at the next blue arrow in real time/online analysis? Polynomial extrapolation? A cubic Bézier curve? A simple cubic function? 
Similar to this image: it is pretty intuitive to continue/extrapolate the red curve into the dotted green curve (in off-line analysis), but how do you do that in real time?
[image]

The SWMA is calculated like this:
[image]

Comment: You can also try linear prediction. See this link for a [nice tutorial](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/linear-prediction-tutorial/) on linear prediction. Calculate the linear prediction of your signal until you get a turning point in the predicted continuation.

Comment: i might be able to comment if i understood what were the original points going into this sine-weighted moving average and then exactly what the "impulse response" is.  i think it might be $$h[n] =  \frac{1}{\pi L} \cos\left( \pi \frac{n+\frac12}{L} \right) $$ for $-\frac{L}{2} \le n < \frac{L}{2} $ (it's acausal but weights samples both forward and backward symmetrically.)

Comment: @ robert bristow-johnson: It does not really matter what the original data points are. The signal going into the SWMA is a stationary, non-periodic signal. I have also shown how the SWMA is calculated: I have edited my post, so you see that it is in fact a causal filter.